# Why don't we separate the verb "weggehen" when we use it in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, separable-verb

I'm learning about the "Trennbare Verben" now. So far, I have learned that some prefixes are separated from the main verb, and that it should be put at the very end of the sentence. I have come across a list, which was titled "Trennbar sind". Some of the verbs are:

- abfahren
- ankommen
- aufstehen
- zurückkommen
- umsteigen

Now, when we use "abfahren", we separate the verb.

> Er fährt ... ab.

However, the verbs "weggehen" and "umsteigen" are not separated when used in a sentence, although they come under the "separable verbs" category. Why is that? And how do I know if the prefix should be put at the end of the sentence or not?

Comment: Where did you learn that those verbs aren’t separated? That’s plain wrong, they behave exactly the same as _abfahren_: _Er geht weg. Er steigt um._

Comment: Are you aware that the infinitive form of a verb is not separated? When using modal verbs, for instance, you say: "Darf ich abfahren?" and **not** "Darf ich fahren ab?" There are further other examples, even finite forms are not always separated.

Comment: @chirlu OP basically said: "These verbs are not separated although they claim they were separated." So, I guess he encountered a sentence in which they're plainly not separated for good reason.

Comment: @Em1: The OP also cited the infinitive _abfahren_ (correctly written unseparated) as an example for a verb that does have a movable prefix.

Comment: @chirlu And in the same list, he mentioned "umsteigen"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have snapped some wrong information. The verbs are separated, just as you would expect.

I suppose you might have seen them in a sentence like:

> Ich will nicht, dass du weggehst.

In this case, when the verb is at the end of a sentence (due to other grammatical rules), we write it together - doesn't matter which prefix it has.